# ColdFusion 8 JavaLoader LingPipe or OpenNLP, how do I init it?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm using the JavaLoader.cfc. I've used it before, but am having trouble understanding how to get one of these libraries to respond to me.

I've placed the JAR files into my java folder. I've created the "JavaLoader" object and passed the "paths" to it. But it keeps saying it cannot find the class names in the jar files or something along those lines...

> The requested class could not be found. The requested class
>   `opennlp.tools.sentdetect` could not be found in the loaded
>   jars/directories.

I recognize I'm a total n00b when it comes to Java and how to tie it in with ColdFusion. I'm sure it's something stupid that IF I KNEW I could probably use any JAR file at my disposal...

Please help if you can!

Comment: it would help if you shared your code to load JavaLoader and initialize it and the Jar files you have included in the paths you pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the OpenNLP javadocs [here](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/api/index.html?opennlp/tools/sentdetect/package-summary.html) and it seems that *opennlp.tools.sentdetect* has no constructor so that's why it returns an error. Which method do you want to call?

I've done a simple example to detect sentences but for that you need to get the english model available [here](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/en-sent.bin) :

```
<cfscript>
// load NLP jar libraries
sourcePaths = [expandPath("opennlp-tools-1.5.0\opennlp-tools-1.5.0.jar"),expandPath("opennlp-tools-1.5.0\lib\maxent-3.0.0.jar"),expandPath("opennlp-tools-1.5.0\lib\jwnl-1.3.3.jar")];
javaloader = createObject("component", "javaloader.JavaLoader").init(sourcePaths);

// load our model (here english model)
// you can create your own model using the TrainerTool
inputFile = ExpandPath("en-sent.bin");
modelIn = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream").init(inputFile);
model = javaloader.create("opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel").init(modelIn);

// let's try the sentence detector
sentenceDetector = javaloader.create("opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME").init(model);
sentences = sentenceDetector.sentDetect("I love working with Java in ColdFusion! CF rocks, really! But sometimes working with Java libraries is a bit tricky :-)");
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#sentences#">
```

Have fun! :-)

Comment: Exactly what I was needing.  Good greetings!

Comment: *it seems that `opennlp.tools.sentdetect` has no constructor* More specifically, it is [path of a package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html), not an actual class and that is why it does not work. `createObject` expects the full path to a [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

No Java expert here either , but I did get POI to work by following Rays instructions [here](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/2/4/Reading-Office-documents-with-ColdFusion) There's two articles. He covers setting up Javaloader

Answer (score 0):

You issue may just be in the path to the JAR.  Also be sure that you are passing the path to the JAR file as a string in an array.

Tip 1: You do not need to place the file in your java folder.  Being able to place the JAR file in any directory (application root perhaps), is what JavaLoader gives you the power to do.  Otherwise you might as well not use JavaLoader and just place the JAR files into the JVM classpath.

Tip 2: Be sure that initialize JavaLoader into the server scope, as it will reduce your overhead dramatically.